# VPN соединение через 3G модем

Tags: vpn, linux

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой.Имеется 3G модем от МТС, сам интернет прекрасно работает как на Linux так и на Windows.Имеется OpanVPN сервер к которому совершаю подключение без особых проблем стандартными утилитами в Linux.

Суть заключается в следующем:Когда включен модем то комманда ping mail.ru нормально отрабатывает, но стоит мне включить VPN соединение и повторный набор команды ping mail.ru выдает что данный хост не найден. При этом если сделать ping 67.69.145.53 то команда отработает.

По моему мнению что-то в этот момент происходит с DNS сервером, или он меняется, или просто затирается соединением.Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

МТС не позволяет чужим абонентам приходить в свой DNS сервер. Задайте в настройках VPN явное прописывание DNS-сервера (8.8.8.8 или 77.88.8.8)Ну или прибейте их наглухо в /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: В данном файле подписано что он изменяется при старте Нетворк Менеджера. Т.е. можно не верить надписи и просто вбивать ДНС ?

Comment: Да, все получилось! Спасибо большое. Целый день ломал голову.Если не секрет, подскажите, есть ли смысл использовать другие, более доступные или быстрые DNS сервера, и как можно данные сервера найти?